# Testing the first line of a Word Document against a specific String

Tags: vba

I am new to VBA and am missing something very obvious but cannot figure out what it is.

I have the following to test if the first line of the document is `Collated Harzard Notes`:

```
Public Sub testDocRANotes()

Dim rng As Range
Dim i As Integer
Dim str As String

Set rng = Selection.GoTo(What:=wdGoToLine, Which:=wdGoToAbsolute, count:=1)
Selection.Expand wdLine
Debug.Print Selection.Text

str = Selection.Text

If (str = "Collated Hazard Notes") Then
    Debug.Print "RA Notes"
Else
    Debug.Print "Not RA Notes"
End If
End Sub
```

When I run it on a document with a first line of 'Collated Hazard Notes', the if returns false and I can't figure out why.  Thanks for taking the time to read.

Answer (score 0):

If you expand the selection to a whole line then that includes the carriage return character at the end of the line:

```
Debug.Print Asc(Right(str, 1)) ' >> 13
```

Try trimming that off with something like:

```
str = Selection.Text
str = Left(str, Len(str) - 1) ' << remove vbCr character
```

Your test should then give the expected results.

Comment: Thanks!  I thought it must be something along those lines.